# Exceptions in Spring service appearing in unexpected places

Tags: java, spring, sockets

I have built a client library in pure Java (no framework, just socket communication) to a server application, and this client library is used within a Spring application.

I am debugging an issue where my client library will catch an `Exception` that appears to be thrown in an unrelated service.

For example, say `ServiceClient` is a wrapper to my client library and `ServiceDB` is a DB service. Then the following may occur:

1. `ServiceDB` gets an `SQL error` and doesn't catch it
2. The library inside `ServiceClient` catches a `Exception` while reading to or sending from a socket, but the message for this exception is an `SQL error`

But `ServiceClient` doesn't rely on or use SQL at all. Furthermore, there is no dependency between `ServiceClient` and `ServiceDB`. The same thing would happen if you replace `ServiceDB` with a web socket service, or similar.

At times, I do see the `DestroyJavaVM` thread running, which I think indicates that Spring is trying to shutdown. However, I'm not positive that this thread runs each time this issue occurs, so it may be unrelated.

*I suspect* this may be caused by some underlying Spring behavior, but I am not aware of what would cause this.

**My question is**: what can cause my service to catch exceptions that appear to be caused in completely unrelated modules?

Comment: I've only understood that you have a client library which is used by another party and it throws exceptions when underlying infrastructure(db, network) fails - that is expected behavior - normally you either wrap exceptions from the underlying layer(specifying that they may happen - "this method may throw IOException(this statement includes case of a more specific subclass of io error) if something fails") in javadoc) or let them pass through, if your logic does not know what to do with that exception, so what is the question?

Comment: Boris, I've updated the question, please let me know if it is unclear. I think you misunderstood my question, because it was poorly worded

Comment: What does "[t]he same thing would happen if you replace ServiceDB with a web socket service, or similar" mean?  If your code calls another service, it can throw exceptions to you, even through a service interface layer.  Is the other library injected into your code for use?

Comment: What kind of communication do you use? RMI? Direct socket to socket? Exceptions can be serialized and send over RMI to the client.

Comment: @WarrenDew, no, as stated in the question, there is no dependency between the service wrapping my library and the service throwing the exception. That is, the service wrapping my library does not in any way use the service throwing the exception, and vice-a-versa. What I mean by "[t]he same thing would happen if you replace ServiceDB with a web socket service, or similar" is that if a different service, say a Web Sockets service, threw an exception, then my (again, independence) library code would also get that exception

Comment: @R4J, this is socket to socket, however, this has nothing to do with an exception being thrown at the connected service. All exceptions happen locally to the server

Comment: Show us the stacktrace of this 'weird' exception.

Comment: I unfortunately do not have one. The last time it happened, the person running the server did not capture it. Many times the message text is straight out of Spring source code, though, from the unrelated services which previously logged an exception. I'm really just trying to understand why this is occurring. I.E., what about how Spring works would cause this?